# How to create WP7 app (VB) which will work in background

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, background-process, visual-studio-2010

I need to create some time scheduled application, which doing tasks by given time. Program waiting in background while phone started. user can stop it when he wants.

Unable find something for WP7.

It will be good if info will be in VB.

Answer (score 0):

This thing is called `Background Agents` and there are plenty of tutorials about that available:

- [Background agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202941%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [How to implement background agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [PeriodicTask Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.periodictask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)